# A problem related to prepositions

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence --------

> A dent ***in*** the door of the car.

For things that touch or are found on surface ***on*** is used.

So can I say

A dent on the door of the car.

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 1):

You are more likely to say **a dent in the door** because dents, unlike marks, actually alter the shape of the door.

Their impact causes the surface metal panel to buckle, leaving an indentation. It's equivalent to making a hole **in** the door.

On the other hand, a mark or scratch is generally **on** the door because it affects only the paintwork, or at least just the surface of the metal rather than the integrity of the panel.

Think of it in terms of the difference between a stain on your shirt and a rip in the fabric.

Comment: But when I looked up the meaning of **indentation** in Cambridge dictionary it showed **a hole or mark on the surface of sth** in this case on is used. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Both "in the door" and "on the door" work, and the meaning is the same.

If it were a *mark* or a *scratch*, it would be "on the door", because it's only on the surface. But a dent is three-dimensional: it makes a hole into the door, so it can be "in" as well as "on".